# typeahead rails 3 autocomplete with user per request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete, typeahead

> The app is using typeahead and bootstrap 3 for, autocomplete function. 
>   but now we have so many records that , it is getting really slower.

```
   var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substrRegex;

            // an array that will be populated with substring matches
            matches = [];

            // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

            // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
            // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
            $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                    // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                    matches.push({ value: str });
                }
            });

            cb(matches);
        };
    };
```

---

```
$('.typeahead').each(function(elem) {
        $(elem).typeahead({
            hint: false,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 3
        }, {
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: substringMatcher($(elem).data('source'))
        });
    });
```

> these are javasxript parts of typeahead fuction used by the app

**on the view side of the form**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="typeahead_book">Title</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input value="<%=@option.book.try(:title)%>" name="option[book_title]" type="text" class="form-control typeahead typeahead-remote-book" id="typeahead_book"  data-provide="typeahead" data-items="10" data-source='<%=@book_titles%>'>
          <p class="help-block"><small><%= $autocomplete_message %></small></p>
        </div>
```

**i use a callback as**

```
before_filter :get_autocomplete_lists, only: [:new, :edit]

def get_autocomplete_lists

    @book_titles = Rails.cache.fetch("booktitles", :force => true, expires_in: 10.minutes) do 
      Book.scoped.map(&:title)
    end


    @publisher_names = Rails.cache.fetch("publishernames", :force => true, expires_in: 10.minutes) do 
      Publisher.all.map(&:name)
    end


    @users_by_email_name = Rails.cache.fetch("users",  :force => true, expires_in: 7.days) do 
      User.scoped.map{|user| "#{user.email} - #{user.name}"}
    end 


    @country_names = Rails.cache.fetch("countrynames",  :force => true, expires_in: 7.days) do
      Country.all.map(&:first).sort
    end
    # @languages = LanguageList::COMMON_LANGUAGES.map(&:name)
    # @country_names = Anatolialit::Country::List.sort
    # 

    @languages = Rails.cache.fetch("languages",  :force => true, expires_in: 7.days) do 
      Anatolialit::Language::EnList.sort
    end

  end
```

> on controller that generates source of the book , as @book_titles , 
>   **THE APP IS WORKING NOW** but i have to refactor the code for **performance** issues.Because after 10k record @book_titles is **very big**.
>
> ---
>
> **THAN WHAT I DID**
>   i created a new controller action on application controller

```
def book_titles
     searchterm = (params[:title])
     books =Book.any_of({ :title => /.*#{searchterm}.*/ })
     respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: books.map(&:title)  }
     end
  end
```

---

> and i defined a route to use as application controller as an api service

```
get 'booktitles/:title' => 'application#book_titles', format: :json
```

> now when i use a localhost:3000/booktitles/the 
>   it brings me as a json data all the books that indicates 'the' in the title.
>   **I think everything Until here is ok.** about refactoring.
>
> ---
>
> but when i use this code below for userside per request for sourcing typeahead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.typeahead-remote-book').typeahead({
      source: function (query, process) {
          return $.get('/booktitles', { query: query }, function (data) {
              return typeahead.process(data);
          });
      }
  });
});
```

---

> and i changed the view part of the form to

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="typeahead_book">Title</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input value="<%=@option.book.try(:title)%>" name="option[book_title]" type="text" class="form-control typeahead typeahead-remote-book" id="typeahead_book"  data-provide="typeahead" data-items="10" >
          <p class="help-block"><small><%= $autocomplete_message %></small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

*I do not know what is wrong with the situation , but it does not work *

could u please help me ? about solving the problem. 
Thanks for your kind help.. 
best regards.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're trying to do realime searching in the database and that is not very efficient.  At least make sure you're indexing books on title. You should have a migration like:

```
class AddIndexOnBookTitles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :books, :title, unique: false #or omit false if dupes not allowed.
  end
end
```

Then you don't want book objects, but just titles, which you should probably cache somewhere. We can talk about that later.

Don't use `.map` on an `ActiveRecordRelation` object but instead `.pluck` to just pluck the fields you need out of the DB.

```
def book_titles
  books = Book.any_of({ :title => /.*#{params[:title]}.*/ }).pluck(:title)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: books }
  end
end
```

That still might be slow if you have a lot of books. But give that a try first and see if it's any better.  If not, we'll need to do some caching or maybe use Elasticsearch which is designed for this type of thing.

Comment: thank you for your kind interest, first of all  i am using a mongodb. And mongoid_search for search indexing and fast search , i think i can use it then, thanks for suggestions ... but it indexes daily with a cron job, and it will cause autocompletion problems for instantaneous records , i have to concentrate on this issue. 

will pluck help me on mongodb, i had a small research on it ... and i think it is useless for mongodb , am i wrong ? I am a noobie , i am trying to learn with practicing, sorry for bothering u :))

Comment: `.pluck` should still be faster.  try it.  also i removed 1 line which you don't need.  Every bit helps.